# How to replace all content main tag from template

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace all content (div header) main tag from template (header div & footer).

```
    <main class="central">
      <div id="main" class="central__content">
        <div id="intro" class="intro"/>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer"/>
    </main>

    <template id="rules">
      <header class="header">
    ...
      </header>
      <div class="rules">
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
    ...
      </footer>
   </template>
```

I think that first step is get content - array of three tags, but content and textConten is empty.

```
var currentTemplate = document.querySelector('#rules');
var divFromTemplate = currentTemplate.content;
```

but divFromTemplate  is empty.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous please make it clear.

Comment: Is there any `.content` property ? I think it's `.textContent` ?

Comment: One reason could be you have invalid HTML. But maybe you could use `currentTemplate.textContent`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes, maybe it should be `.textContent` which the OP is trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

The `querySelector()` function returns an `Element` object which has no property called `content`. You may want to try the Outer Html or textContent for better performance.

Reference for the Element Object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Reference for querySelector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector